# What is the typescript loader script to disable console.log functions in production mode in webstorm?

Tags: typescript

There are two npms' I have found so far (strip-loader and webpack-loader) which do similar task but they are for javascript. Question is what will i do for loading typescript?

Comment: typescript gets should be compiled to javascript before is sent to the browser. Otherwise you'd have to do the compilation from typescript to javascript on all the clients. That will lead to very slow page loads. There are typescript transpilers that will work in the browser but it is not recommended you use them in production.

Comment: also.. the title and body of your question don't seem to be about the same thing.

Comment: You might also want to read the how to ask guide, it will help you get better answers. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: plnkr is doing it, you can check their setup for Angular applications with typescript.

Comment: @toskv my title and body are targeting same issue.. plz read again... i want to use the javascript loader codes (got from npms) as typescript loader. The problem i want to solve here is to disable console.log from production. Its simple as that. :/